# Click on a non-select dropdown option using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, drop-down-menu, webdriverwait

I am trying to automate some task as download file and pre-process them. To download one of them I need to specify dates (I can't share the website because of privacy) but I am not able to select between Dec-2022 and Jan-2023 as an example below:

Here is HTML code:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="clickDrop($event)" ng-show="showButton()" data-wt="toggle">
         <span class="ng-binding">Current Month</span>
         <span ng-hide="dropOpen" class="caret ng-hide"></span>
         <span ng-show="dropOpen" class="dropup"><span class="caret"></span></span>
     </button>
 <div class="rpt-dext-select-dropdown-options" data-wt="dropdown" ng-show="isEditable()">
 <div ng-repeat="option in options|filter:{label:searchFilter}" ng-click="selectOption(option,$event)" class="rpt-dext-select-dropdown-checkable ng-scope" data-wt="202301">   <span ng-class="{'rpt-dext-select-dropdown-checked':selections.includes(option)}" class="ng-binding">Jan 2023</span>
                <span class="fas fa-check check-mark ng-hide" ng-show="selections.includes(option)"></span>
             </div>
 <div ng-repeat="option in options|filter:{label:searchFilter}" ng-click="selectOption(option,$event)" class="rpt-dext-select-dropdown-checkable ng-scope" data-wt="202212">   <span ng-class="{'rpt-dext-select-dropdown-checked':selections.includes(option)}" class="ng-binding">Dec 2022</span>
                <span class="fas fa-check check-mark ng-hide" ng-show="selections.includes(option)"></span>
             </div>
```

I can open the menu  :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.ng-isolate-scope:nth-child(3) .ng-isolate-scope~ .ng-isolate-scope button .ng-binding'))).click()
```

But not able to select with `click()` and I think select() doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you open the menu using the line of code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.ng-isolate-scope:nth-child(3) .ng-isolate-scope~ .ng-isolate-scope button .ng-binding'))).click()
```

To click on an option you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Click on *Dec 2022*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='rpt-dext-select-dropdown-options']//span[@class='ng-binding' and text()='Dec 2022']"))).click()
  ```
- Click on *Jan 2023*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='rpt-dext-select-dropdown-options']//span[@class='ng-binding' and text()='Jan 2023']"))).click()
  ```